# How to replace a string in pandas column based on a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I am trying to check if values in column are numbers and replace them with other strings. I am using the code

```
df["recs"] = ["45", "emp1", "12", "emp3", "emp4", "emp5"]
recomm = df["recs"]
# check if the values in each row of this column a number
recomm = recomm.str.replace(recomm.isdigit(), 'Number')
```

But it is generating an error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str.replace` here with the regex pattern `^\d+$`:

```py
df["recs"] = df["recs"].str.replace(r'^\d+$', 'Number')
```

The pattern `^\d+$` targets only string values which are pure numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer without regex and with `mask`:

```
df['recs'] = df['recs'].mask(df['recs'].str.isdigit(), 'Number')
```